# Dependency properties concept

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I don't understand the Wpf dependency properties use.
Can anybody explain what is it and it’s use and how to use and learn simple the concept.

Comment: Probably you should read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency properties work much like ordinary properties, but you can set their values in XAML. For example, take the following dependency property declaration made in a class called MyCustomControl:

```cs
public bool EditMode
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(EditModeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EditModeProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty EditModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EditMode", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I can now set the EditMode property in the tag itself:

```xml
<controls:MyCustomControl EditMode="True"/>
```

Dependency properties also raise PropertyChanged events, so you can bind to them without having to implement INotifyPropertyChanged yourself.